# how to make pushViewController: work in the following case?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller embedded in a RootViewController. The elements present inside the RootViewController are a segmented control and a UIView. As the different segments are selected, the UIView displays a corresponding ViewController.

Now each of the ViewController being displayed in the UIView is a UITableViewController.

I need to display the table values as per the segment selections. And also if any of the row of the table is selected, it has to move to a newer ViewController with the detailed view.

I am able to display the UITableViewControllers as per the segment change. However, when i click on the row of the table, the newer ViewController that comes up is blank (Black Screen) even though I have created the particular ViewController in the Storyboard and set up an identifier as well.

**Code for the Segmented Control change in ViewController.m**

```
- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl*)segmentedControl {

int selIndex = segmentedControl.selectedIndex;

if (selIndex == 0)
{
    aTable = [[aTableViewController alloc] init];

    aTable.view.frame = self.myView.bounds;
    [self.myView addSubview:aTable.view];
    [self addChildViewController:aTable];
}

if (selIndex == 1)
{
    bTable = [[bTableViewController alloc] init];

    bTable.view.frame = self.myView.bounds;
    [self.myView addSubview:bTable.view];
    [self addChildViewController:bTable];

}

if (selIndex == 2)
{
    //NSLog (@"Well you selected a 3rd option");
}}
```

**Code for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

newDetailController* newController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];

newController = [[newDetailController alloc] init];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];}
```

The pushViewController pushes an empty view for me even though I have specified the ViewController to use in the Storyboard design and also using an identifier.

Please help me in understanding what I must do to rectify this error.

**UPDATE - The above problem has been resolved.**

The problem I face now is being unable to access the data in the newViewController.

I pass the data to the newViewController as follows:

1. Create a class named newClass which contains all the elements I want to pass across.
2. Create a NSMutableArray "newObjects" in the firstViewController.
3. Create each newClass object at this method.

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
     {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   customBigTableCell *cell = (customBigTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[customBigTableCell alloc] init];
   }

   cell.name.text = [object objectForKey:@"objName"];

   newClass* newObj = [[newClass alloc] init];

   newObj.objName = cell.name.text;

   [newObjects addObject:newObj];

   return cell;
   }

   Pls pardon me .. for the indenting with the code block is messed up...
   Also the PFObject is cos i use Parse for database.
4. Add the created object to the newObjects array.
5. In the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, this is the code

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

     newDetailController* newController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UpcomingDetail"];

     obj = [[newClass alloc] init];

     NSIndexPath* path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

     obj = [newObjects objectAtIndex:path.row];

     NSLog(@"Row selected is %ld", (long)path.row); //this returns the correct row selected

     NSLog(@"Movie selected is %@", [[newObjects objectAtIndex:path.row] objName]);//however this is not the right one as per the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

     [newController setNewObj:obj];

     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
     }

When I run this code, the row is selected correctly. However I dont get the corresponding row in the database. The array gets stored with redundant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of that middle line:

```
newController = [[newDetailController alloc] init];
```

That just redefines newController (as an empty controller with no view set up), which you defined in the first line.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar. However, when i remove that statement, I get the following error...

Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x9656a30>

Comment: Also, I checked on similar questions and they asked me not to override the -(void)loadView method. However, I do not have that method overridden in my program.

Comment: @AJoseph, if you're getting that error, then for some reason the line above is not returning a view controller. You should log both newController and self.storyboard to see which is nil. Also, you probably shouldn't override loadView -- why are you doing that?

Comment: @rdelmar... I was not overriding the loadView method. I said the solutions to similar questions were that but I am not having any loadView method.

As per your suggestion, i checked both the navigation controller and the storyboard. The navigation controller I already checked. But the storyboard was NIL now and i changed it to point to MainStoryboard and now the pushViewController works. Thanks very much for your assistance.

Comment: I do have another issue if you dont mind answering. I am actually passing some data from this particular ViewController to the next. However, the data is not being displayed properly and also when i use NSLog, i see viewDidLoad () method being called multiple times.

Comment: @AJoseph, You should update your question with how you're trying to pass the data, so I can see what you're doing. Also show the code for the log where you see viewDidLoad called multiple times.IF se,f.storyboard was nil, that must be because that controller (with the table view) isn't in a storyboard. Did you create that one in code or use a xib file instead?

Comment: @rdelmar.. I will update my question by the evening. I am not near my machine now. However, The pushViewController method works fine. The storyboard is the XIB file and the ViewController with the identifier exists in the same storyboard. That issue has been resolved.